# Redirecting using wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, url, hyperlink, redirect

First question in here, so be gentle with me:)

Much easier to explain with examples of the url.

This is one of the current url's

```
 domainname.com/loc/window-repair/england/
```

We now need to lose the /loc/ part of the url so that it would now point to

```
 www.domainname.com/window-repair/england/
```

The problem is that it isnt just one url, there are approxcimately 1000 urls pointing to various destinations in the UK all with the loc part in the url, and they all have sub directories.

eg

```
 domainname.com/loc/window-repair/england/north-east/darlington
```

or

```
 domainname.com/loc/window-repair/england/north-east/
```

or

```
 domainname.com/loc/window-repair/scotland/
```

How can I put in a redirect so that the link still works but without the loc part.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htaccess file:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)/(.*)/?$ /loc/$1-$2/$3
```